# Преобразовать из byte[] в Bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, drawable

Есть поле типа byte[], нужно его сконвертировать в Bitmap, это необходимо для дальнейшего преобразования в Drawable. В bytes точно содержаться элементы. Я перепробовал следующие варианты:

```
//bytes - целевой массив
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
Drawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmp)
```

и

```
//bytes - целевой массив
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.lenght);
Drawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmp)
```

И тот, и другой варианты выдают null, и таким образом я не могу получить Drawable.
Если есть другие идеи по превращению byte[] в Drawable - буду рад вашим предложениям)
И желательно, конечно, не использовать посторонние библиотеки. Благодарю!

Answer (score 0):

Вот утилиты из моего приложения опубликованного в Google Play. Код 100% рабочий

```
public static byte[] bitmapToByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream_edit_post_image = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream_edit_post_image);
    return stream_edit_post_image.toByteArray();
}

public static Bitmap byteArrayToBitmap(byte[] bytes) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
}

public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {

    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) return ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}

public static Drawable bitmapToDrawable (Context context, Bitmap bitmap) {

    Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);

    return drawable;
}
```

Comment: Cпасибо большое, не знаете, почему метод "decodeByteArray" может возвращать null?